# Strange behaviour when allocating char**

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to create an array of strings and fill it with the character '0' using a function. The code looks like this:

```
void    init_array(char **array)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 4)
    {
        array[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
        j = 0;
        while (j < 4)
        {
            array[i][j] = '0';
            array[i][4] = '\0';
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char **c;
    c = (char**)malloc(sizeof(**c) * 4);
    init_array(c);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%s\n", c[i]);
}
```

This prints the array with 0's, except for the first line, which displays weird characters (question marks and such). Strangely, if I change the value of `i` in the `init_array` function to `-1`, then the whole array gets displayed properly. Could anyone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Out of context as this has already been answered but you could do your loop like that:

EDIT: Code formatting is really bad in comments. Basically the idea is the move this `array[i][4] = '\0';` 2 lines underneath like: `array[i][j] = '\0';`

Answer (score 4):

`**c` is of type `char`, so `sizeof(**c)` is 1. Replace the fist array allocation with:

```
c = (char**)malloc(sizeof(*c) * 4);
```